# how to store values in array php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code to display list of questions and 4 options( using option box). user has to select the correct option . Is it possible to store the user selected options in array variable. There may be 10 to 20 questions array variable should contain only option values.

```
<?php 
require('connect.php'); 
$display=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Java_Test_1 ORDER BY id ASC"); 
echo "<form method=post action=$PHP_SELF>"; 
echo "<table border=0>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) 
{ 
$id=$row['0']; 
$question=$row['1']; 
$opta=$row['2']; 
$optb=$row['3'];  
$optc=$row['4']; 
$optd=$row['5']; 
$answer = $row["woptcode"]; 
echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>$opta<input type=radio name=$id value='a'></input></td><td>$optb <input        type=radio name=$id value='b'></input></td><td>$optc <input type=radio name=$id value='c'> </input></td><td>$optd <input type=radio name=$id value='d'></input></td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo "<input type='submit' value='start' name='doo'>"; 
echo "</form>"; 
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for multiple selections, perhaps you should use the `checkbox` input type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = 'opt';
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) 
{ 


 $name = 'opt'.$counter;
 $counter++;

$id=$row['0']; 

$question=$row['1']; 
$opta=$row['2']; 
$optb=$row['3'];  
$optc=$row['4']; 
$optd=$row['5']; 
$answer = $row["woptcode"]; 
echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>$opta<input type=radio name=$name value='a'></td>
<td>$optb <input type=radio name=$name value='b'></td>
<td>$optc <input type=radio name=$name value='c'></td>
<td>$optd <input type=radio name=$name value='d'></td>
</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: An explanation would go a *long* way here.

Comment: Now am using name = $id . as per u said i changed to opt[] ,i have to question each as 4 option. after i changed to opt[] i can select only one option out of all 10 question

Comment: So that's what radio buttons do. If you want to select multiple options, user <input type='chechbox' name='opt[]' value='xyz' />

Comment: [link]http://chitiknowit.com/Test/que.php jus take a look at this u will understand ..

Comment: I tried your code. counter value is increasing . but cannot select the options. same problem..

Comment: Now its working i change Counter ++ ; to Counter = counter +4

Comment: You can apply same logic for printing also. $name = 'opt';
$counter = 0; then run a loop and increment the counter in that loop. Then you can print for eg $_POST['opt'.$counter]

Comment: i tried this code but its not at all working $name=$_POST['opt'.$counter];
 for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
  echo $name;
  }

Comment: You are doing it wrong for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { $name=$_POST['opt'.$i];echo $name; }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation that expains this in detail

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php
Section: How do I create arrays in a HTML ?